# What type of caulk and/or sealant for my tub? See image

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, caulk, sealant

I have a relatively old tub and tile work in our master bath. I’ve re-caulked it a few times and even did a sealant along one edge, but I think I need to use something stronger. Here’s some pics - let me know what specifically you all suggest please. https://imgur.com/gallery/QNYFn1o

[image: stripped tub]
[image: corner]

Comment: Are you removing and cleaning where the old caulk was?  Do you fill the tub with water before placing caulk?

Comment: Yes, as the photos show I’m in the process of removing and cleaning. And I wasn’t planning on adding water before caulking cuz it needs to be dry, but are you suggesting that cuz it drops the tub a bit with all the weight? I’ve not heard of that but I’m not a plumber or expert by any means

Comment: I think he meant to fill the tub so that the caulk cures in the *loaded* condition...

Comment: Got it, so that’s a common and suggested practice?

Comment: That picture in the corner of the tub is odd. Is the top surface of the tile aligned with the top surface of the tub? If so, then there's no way that's correctly waterproofed. Your tile looks almost stone-like. Does this tile have "open pores" to absorb water? Or is most any absorbed water absorbed through the grout lines? And the flat tile, what size is the gap between the tub's edge and the tile's edge where they meet? And this is at the tub's relatively dry end? Maybe you could get that joint cleaned out and get another picture with some common object like a coin in frame for scale.

Comment: "Stronger"? Is the caulk debonding from the tile or tub surface? Tearing between the back corner of the caulk bead and its face? And what kind of caulk have you been using? What was the sealant?